# How to cut filename from URL?

Tags: python, html, string

I have a lot of links like this `http://example.com/2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html` or `http://example.com/2013/89/i2013i89p60003.html`.

I need to save the HTML file in the folder `1520` as `i2013i1520p100049.html` and the file in the folder "89" as `i2013i89p60003.html`, respectively.

I could to cut string but others have another length.

P.S. I'm using Python.

Answer (score 4):

Use `split()`

```
url   = 'http://example.com/2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html'
parts = url.split('/')

fn  = parts[-1]
dir = parts[-2]
```

Then make the call, save the source:

```
import urllib2

fp = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

fullpath_fn = dir + '/' + fn
with open(fullpath, 'w') as htmlfile:
    htmlfile.write(fp)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [urlparse.urlsplit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) and [os.path.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split):

```
import os
import urlparse
s = 'http://example.com/2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html'

path = urlparse.urlsplit(s).path
print(path)
# /2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html

dirname, basename = os.path.split(path)
dirname, basedir = os.path.split(dirname)
print(basedir)
# 1520
print(basename)
# i2013i1520p100049.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following (if you wanted to do more complex work on it):

```
s = 'http://example.com/2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html'

from operator import itemgetter
from urlparse import urlsplit

split_url = urlsplit(s)
path, fname = itemgetter(2, -1)(split_url.path.split('/'))
print path, fname
# 1520 i2013i1520p100049.html
```

Otherwise:

```
path, fname = s.rsplit('/', 2)[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`split()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm):

```
url = 'http://example.com/2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html'
tokens = url.split('/')
file = parts[-1]
folder = parts[-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of it, a regex-based answer:

```
match = re.search(r'([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+\.html)$', string)
if match:
    folder = match.group(1)
    file = match.group(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So using this standardized format the fastest way would be to use a find and a slice :). Regex's would not be worth it

e.g.

```
>>> a = "http://example.com/2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html or http://example.com/2013/89/i2013i89p60003.html"
>>> lastindex = a.rfind('/')
>>> a[lastindex+1:]
'i2013i89p60003.html'
>>> a[a.rfind('/',0,lastindex)+1:lastindex]
'89'
```

split vs find in a giant url (yes these exist, but not usually *this* big)

```
>>> a = range(10000)
>>> [a.insert(randint(0,10000),'/') for x in range(0,100)]
>>> a = str(a)
>>> b = time.time(); a.rfind('/'); time.time()-b
58493
1.8835067749023438e-05
>>> b = time.time(); d=a.split('/'); time.time()-b
0.00012683868408203125
```

more importantly you don't need to make a giant reallocation / copy of your list which is not fun when you have 1000's of URL's

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'http://example.com/2013/1520/i2013i1520p100049.html'.split('/')[-1]
'i2013i1520p100049.html'
```